# Convergence in Probability of Stochastic Integral

Tags: probability, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Question: Let $W$ be a Wiener process, and $H$, an adapted, right-continuous, bounded process. Prove that for a fixed $t$,
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{W_{t+h} - W_t}\int_t^{t+h} H_s dW_s = H_t$$

in probability.

My attempt: Since we need to prove convergence in the sense of probability, we need to consider 
$$P(|\frac{1}{W_{t+h} - W_t}\int_t^{t+h} H_s dW_s - H_t| > \epsilon).$$

By Markov's inequality, we know that the above probability is less than or equal to 
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon}E[|\frac{1}{W_{t+h} - W_t}\int_t^{t+h} H_s dW_s - H_t|].$$
Since $t$ is fixed, we can state the following
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon}E[|\frac{1}{W_{t+h} - W_t}\int_t^{t+h} H_s dW_s - H_t|] =\frac{1}{\epsilon}E[|\frac{1}{W_{t+h} - W_t}\int_t^{t+h} H_s - H_t dW_s|].$$

From here, I have considered using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to state that

$$E[|\frac{1}{W_{t+h} - W_t}\int_t^{t+h} H_s - H_t dW_s|] \leq \bigg(E[\frac{1}{W_{t+h}-W_t}]^2\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg(E\big[\int_t^{t+h} H_s - H_t dW_s\big]^2\bigg)^{1/2}$$

$$\leq \bigg(E[\frac{1}{W_{t+h}-W_t}]^2\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg(E\big[\int_t^{t+h} (H_s - H_t)^2 ds\big]\bigg)^{1/2}.$$

At this point, I have come to problem of $\bigg(E[\frac{1}{W_{t+h}-W_t}]^2\bigg)^{1/2}$.

Any advice. Also, I have been given a hint to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on $E\big[|\frac{1}{W_\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon(H_u-H_0)dW_u|^{1/4}\big]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use a slightly different approach for this.  First, it's enough to show $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{W_t}\int_0^t H_s dW_s = H_0$.  For any $t > 0$ and $K > 0$ we have
\begin{align*}
P\left(\left|\frac{1}{W_t}\int_0^t H_s dW_s - H_0\right|>\varepsilon\right) &= P\left(\left|\frac{1}{W_t}\int_0^t (H_s - H_0) dW_s\right|>\varepsilon\right) \\
&= P\left(\left|\frac{1}{W_t}\int_0^t (H_s - H_0) dW_s\right|>\varepsilon, \frac{\sqrt{t}}{|W_t|} \le K \right) \\
&\qquad + P\left(\left|\frac{1}{W_t}\int_0^t (H_s - H_0) dW_s\right|>\varepsilon, \frac{\sqrt{t}}{|W_t|} > K \right) \\
&\le P\left(\left|\frac{K}{\sqrt t}\int_0^t (H_s - H_0) dW_s\right|>\varepsilon \right) + P\left( \frac{\sqrt{t}}{|W_t|} > K \right).
\end{align*}
The idea of doing this is that the $\frac 1{|W_t|}$ is the biggest problem because it can be very large, so we want to split this probability into where $\frac 1{|W_t|}$ is large and where $\frac 1{|W_t|}$ is small and address the two cases separately.

For the first term, by Markov's inequality we have
\begin{align*}
P\left(\left|\frac{K}{\sqrt t}\int_0^t (H_s - H_0) dW_s\right|>\varepsilon \right) &\le \frac{K^2}{\varepsilon t} \mathbb{E}\left[\left|\int_0^t (H_s - H_0) dW_s\right|^2\right] \\
&= \frac{K^2}{\varepsilon t} \mathbb{E}\left[\left|\int_0^t (H_s - H_0)^2 ds\right|\right] \\
&\le \frac{K^2}{\varepsilon t} \mathbb{E}\left[t \sup_{s \le t}|H_s - H_0|^2 \right] \\
&= \frac{K^2}{\varepsilon} \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{s \le t}|H_s - H_0|^2 \right].
\end{align*}
Since $H$ is right-continuous, $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \sup_{s \le t}|H_s(\omega) - H_0(\omega)|^2 = 0$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$, and since $H$ is bounded, the dominated convergence theorem gives $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{K^2}{\varepsilon} \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{s \le t}|H_s - H_0|^2 \right] = 0.$$

For the second term, we have
\begin{align*}
P\left( \frac{\sqrt{t}}{|W_t|} > K \right) &= P\left(\frac{|W_t|}{\sqrt{t}} < \frac 1K \right) = P\left(|Z| < \frac 1K\right)
\end{align*}
where $Z \sim N(0,1)$.  Thus, we have

\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} P\left(\left|\frac{1}{W_t}\int_0^t H_s dW_s - H_0\right|>\varepsilon\right) &\le \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\left(P\left(\left|\frac{K}{\sqrt t}\int_0^t (H_s - H_0) dW_s\right|>\varepsilon \right) + P\left( \frac{\sqrt{t}}{|W_t|} > K \right) \right) \\
&= 0 + P\left(|Z| < \frac 1K\right),
\end{align*}
so now sending $K \rightarrow \infty$ gives $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} P\left(\left|\frac{1}{W_t}\int_0^t H_s dW_s - H_0\right|>\varepsilon\right) = 0$ as desired.

Comment: Beautiful answer (+1) ! Just a question : it is very clear how this argument can be adapted to show that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{W_{t+h} - W_t}\int_t^{t+h} H_s dW_s = H_t$, but why do you claim that it is directly implied by the fact that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{W_t}\int_0^t H_s dW_s = H_0$ ? It seems to me that due to the time dependency, the random variables involved don't necessarily have the same distribution. Or do they ?

Comment: @StratosFair My thinking was just that we could define $\tilde W_s := W_{t+s}-W_t$ (which is a standard Brownian motion with respect to $\mathcal G_s := \mathcal F_{t+s}$) and $\tilde H_s := H_{t+s}$ so that $\frac{1}{W_{t+h}-W_t} \int_t^{t+h} H_s dW_s = \frac{1}{\tilde W_h} \int_0^h \tilde H_s d\tilde W_s$ and we can apply the $t=0$ result.  Maybe there are some subtleties I'm overlooking, though.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense, thank you !